# How to increase the height and width of the image using bitmap

Tags: android

I have created a class call ImageLoader and use memory cache to store all my images parsed from the web and have use the DisplayImage method where i pass th url and the imageview is the layout where to display the image ,

the problem is i want to increase the height and width of the image i have tried from the layout to increase but it is not increasing for reference here is the layout

```
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
  {
   list_of_image = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
   imageViews.put(imageView, url);
   Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);  

        if(bitmap!=null)
         {
          imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
          ///list_of_image.add(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap2));
        }            
       else
      {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

1. you may specify [`android:scaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) attribute for your
   `ImageView`;
2. you may downscale/upscale the bitmap with
   [`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
   boolean filter)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: thank you i have used Android:scaletypr=fitXY and it works for me